# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'frame_00_delay-0.04s.png' -> '0.png'

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, module, file-not-found

```
import os

for i in range(47):
    if i < 10:
        fileName = f"frame_0{i}_delay-0.04s.png"
    else:
        fileName = f"frame_{i}_delay-0.04s.png"
    os.rename(fileName, f"{i}.png")
```

I want to rename 47 files and every file has a '.' in its name. When I wrote a program to rename bunch of files i am getting this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'frame_00_delay-0.04s.png' -> '0.png'
```

All files are png files,
[Here is the screenshot in where you can see how the names of files looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUaMv.png)

Please help me to solve this error.

Comment: Is it possible the extension is `.PNG` iso `.png`?

Comment: Can you add `print(os.listdir())` before your for-loop and check the output?

Answer (score 0):

- As a better practice you should use, you will loop over the files and keep track of a counter at the same time.

```py
for count, file_name in enumerate(os.listdir()):
    Your_for_loop_body
```

- This way, makes you avoid naming errors, as you loop over the files themselves rather than hard coding the names.